# Why TCS MockVita is showing RunTime error for this python code

Tags: python-3.x, list

Can Anyone help me with this. I'm getting runtime error for this in online editor as well as in uploading the file but works with correct output in VS Code.

This is the Online Editor of TCS MockVita
[image]

This is the same code in VSCode
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see the issue but have you the file name with which you've saved your code on the online editor is the same to that on VS code cuz it is bound to throw RE in case they're different.